# i have problem in generating pwm in steps

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm

Given below is my loop and it counts 1 to 250 using the push button i just added this part as this one is the main part. I want to make it in steps like one press (push button) SETS IT TO 10 OR 20 ETC. Many thanks in advance for your kindness.

```
if ((digitalRead(2)==HIGH) && (digitalRead(7)==LOW))
 {
   if (j<255)
   {j++;
   lcd.setCursor(5,1);
   lcd.print("                ");
   lcd.setCursor(5,1);
   lcd.print(j);
   while((digitalRead(2)==HIGH) && (digitalRead(7)==LOW));}
 }
else if ((digitalRead(2)==LOW) && (digitalRead(7)==HIGH))
 {
   if (j>0)
   {j--;
   lcd.setCursor(5,1);
   lcd.print("                ");
   lcd.setCursor(5,1);
   lcd.print(j);
   while((digitalRead(2)==LOW) && (digitalRead(7)==HIGH));}
}

analogWrite(9,j);
//lcd.noDisplay();
lcd.display();
delay(100);

}
```

Comment: the title says `i have a problem` ... there is nothing said about a problem in your post ... what happens when you run the program?

Comment: Where is `j` defined? What do you see on the LCD?

Comment: If you want to change `j` in bigger steps, just replace `j++` and `j--` by for example `j+=10` and `j-=10`. Though I suspect that thats not all of the problem

Comment: I actually added the part in which i was having trouble so the j was defined at the start of the code while i have posted the main part of the code (not the full code). I think comment from Chrisl has solved the problem i was facing, i'll try it later and update it here if its solved. Thanks a lot for your precious time.

Comment: Finally thanks Chrisl to understand my question and helping me out. It worked.